# Random error on winston-daily-rotate-file on azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, node-modules, winston

I'm running on Azure App Service with Node 14.15.1, winston 3.3.3 and winston-daily-rotate-file 4.5.5

I found following error randomly, when the file were rotate.

Not sure what I do wrong and how can I resolve this. Any suggestion are really appreciate.

Thanks in advance,

Error

```
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445079522Z events.js:292
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445119022Z       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445125323Z       ^
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445129523Z 
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445134423Z Error: EIO: i/o error, close
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445137623Z Emitted 'error' event at:
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445140523Z     at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/node_modules/file-stream-rotator/FileStreamRotator.js:677:15)
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445143723Z     at WriteStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445146423Z     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445149223Z     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445153323Z     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445157723Z   errno: -5,
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445162223Z   code: 'EIO',
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445166623Z   syscall: 'close'
2021-10-20T00:00:44.445170323Z
```

Code for logging

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.splat(),
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format.printf(info => {
            return `${tsFormat()} | ${info.level} | ${ info.message }`;
        })
    ),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
            dirname: logDir,
            filename: '%DATE%-KBK.log',
            datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            zippedArchive: true
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am following this  [blog](https://medium.com/@akshaypawar911/how-to-use-winston-daily-rotate-file-logger-in-nodejs-1e1996d2d38) . I am not facing any kind of issue.

For logging you can use the below snippet of Code

```
const winston = require(“winston”);
const DailyRotateFile = require(“winston-daily-rotate-file”);
const config = require(“config”);
const logFormat = winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.colorize(),
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.align(),
    winston.format.printf(
    info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`,
),);

const transport = new DailyRotateFile({
    filename: config.get(“logConfig.logFolder”) +  config.get(“logConfig.logFile”),
    datePattern: ‘YYYY-MM-DD-HH’,
    zippedArchive: true,
    maxSize: ‘20m’,
    maxFiles: ‘14d’,
    prepend: true,
    level: config.get(“logConfig.logLevel”),
});

transport.on(‘rotate’, function (oldFilename, newFilename) {
    // call function like upload to cloud
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: logFormat,
    transports: [
    transport,
    new winston.transports.Console({
    level: “info”,}),
]});
module.exports = logger;
```

Still you are facing the issue try to change the running port of Nodejs the `EIO: i/o error, close` states that Port being used by some other process.